# Reader Beware, You're In For a

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I can keep you grounded, or I can rile you up.
>
> I can facilitate your travel, or I can discourage you from going.
>
> I have assumed many forms including that of a cyborg, a professor, and a statue.

**What am I?**

Hint:

> As long as people desire entertainment, my forms are seemingly endless.

Hint #2:

> Two of my other notable forms are a schizophrenic mind, and a sled.

Hint #3:

> The forms I have explicitly mentioned are, essentially, intangible. Some of the clues in the main body of puzzle point toward tangible items.

Hint #4:

> The wordplay here is playing with multiple definitions. The “forms” apply to only one of these definitions.

Comment: Does rot13(pubbfr lbhe bja nqiragher?) relate to your hint?

Comment: Not exactly, no.

Comment: does it have to do with rot13(zbivrf) possibly rot13(sebz n fcrpvsvp pbzcnal?)

Comment: rot13(Vg vf erfgevpgrq arvgure gb n fcrpvsvp pbzcnal abe gb zbivrf va trareny, gubhtu zbivrf ner n cevzr rknzcyr.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on TwoBitOperation's answer, I'm guessing its

> Spoiler

I can keep you grounded

> A car spoiler keeps it grounded

I can rile you up

> Being spoiled makes people angry

I can facilitate your travel

> Spoilers on plane wings help them fly

I can discourage you from going

> If something is spoiled for you, you don't want to go as much

Everything regarding the hints and the forms is laid out in TwoBitOperation's answer, but in summary

> Each form is a famous spoiler

Also, for the title

> A reader should beware a spoiler when reading a book

Comment: Ah, of course! I think you have it!

Comment: Couldn't have done it without you getting most of the way there!

Comment: Well done! I was impressed with many of the answers this question received, but this one is the intended answer.

Answer (score 6):

**You could be a**

> shock

**Name of the puzzle**

> "You are in for a shock" is a phrase

**I can keep you grounded**

> An electric shock could fuse circuitry so that there is a short to ground

**Or I can rile you up**

> A shock can be a disturbance causing instability.  A person who is shocked can be upset or outraged.

**I can facilitate your travel**

> Shock absorbers or "shocks" in a vehicle make a smoother ride, helping you drive

**I can discourage you from going**

> Entering medical shock can prevent people from dying or "going to the other side"

**I have assumed many forms including that of a cyborg**

> Not sure about this one.  Lots of enemies in System Shock are cyborgs.  Also, there is an EDM song called "cyborg shock".

**A professor**

> Professor Shock from the Goosebumps books

**A statue**

> There's a company called "Pop Culture Shock", who make statues of game figures

Comment: Good effort, but this answer is incorrect.

Comment: The main answer, or some clue explanations?

Comment: The main answer and the explanations are incorrect.

Comment: Is it at all related to ROT13(Gur Tbbfrohzcf senapuvfr)?  Because, ROT13(Ernqre Orjner, Lbh'er Va Sbe n FPNER)

Comment: rot13(Ab, vg'f whfg n cynl ba gur Tbbfrohzcf gntyvar. V qba'g zrna gb FPNER gur ernqre, ohg...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100716/discussion-between-david-robie-and-cgreen).

Comment: I really thought @DavidRobie had the answer since rot13(gur Perrcl Perngvbaf bs Cebsrffbe Fubpx obbx pbagnvaf obgu n fgnghr naq n plobet!)

Answer (score 4):

First incorrect guess was

> <s>Twist</s>

Second guess:

Are you are a:

> Plot? (ie, a plot twist)

I can keep you grounded, or I can rile you up.

> 'Plot' as in literally a piece of land, or 'plot' as in a scheme

I can facilitate your travel, or I can discourage you from going.

> 'Plot' as in a plan of action, or an unexpected incident

a cyborg, a professor, and a statue, schizophrenic mind, and a sled.

> All are the main focus of famous plot twists:  Blade Runner, Harry Potter, Planet of the Apes, Fight Club, Citizen Kane

Hint: As long as people desire entertainment, my forms are seemingly endless.

> This fits the 'intangible' def of plot.  There are always new stories being made

EDIT:  I feel like I'm basically there, and this question has stagnated.  Can I get one more hint so I or someone else can push this over the line?

Comment: Your word is incorrect. rot13(Lbhe nanylfvf bs gur uvagf (gur zbivrf) vf nyzbfg cresrpg, gubhtu!!)

Comment: I've added a second guess

Comment: Props for connecting your guess to the clues, and rot13(lbh'er npghnyyl abg sne bss, gurzngvpnyyl fcrnxvat.) See if you can find a word that also connects to the title somehow.

Comment: rot13(Fhecevfr?)

Comment: Professor suggestion: rot13(Cebsrffbe Fancr va Uneel Cbggre)

Answer (score 2):

> Brad Garret.

I can facilitate your travel:

> Garret voiced Chug, a fuel truck in the movie Planes

Cyborg:

> Garret voiced Krang in the TMNT Movie

Statue:

> Garret voiced the Easter Island Head in Night at the Museum.

Still not sure about all the clues.

Comment: Sorry, this is not on the right track. The answer is one word.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer, but you might be

> The letter X

I don't have anything for the first 2 lines yet, but:

*I have assumed many forms including that of a cyborg, a professor, and a statue.*

> Dr. X is a cyborg villain from Action Man, and also a doctor I guess, but if that's not good enough, Professor X from the X-Men is far more well known.  And there's a number of famous statues of Malcolm X.

*As long as people desire entertainment, my forms are seemingly endless.*

> The only thing I can think of here is NSFW...  But there's certainly a wide variety of XXX entertainment...

Comment: rot13(Ubj K-pvgvat!) But this is not the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a shot because the title strongly reminded me of

> Goosebumps

**Reader beware, you're in for a**

> scare

I can keep you grounded, or I can rile you up.

> Fear can keep you rooted to the spot, or activate your fight or flight response.

I can facilitate your travel, or I can discourage you from going.

> With the fight or flight response you run faster, or fear can stop you from going in the first place.

I have assumed many forms including that of a cyborg, a professor, and a statue.

> Not fully sure of all the references, but maybe Terminator(cyborg), Frankenstein?(professor). Quite sure the statue refers to the Weeping Angels.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark here:

> Paradox

I can facilitate your travel:

> Assuming we're talking about time travel, creating a paradox may or may not stop you from wanting/needing to time travel

Cyborg/Professor

> Professor Paradox was/is both of those things  https://ben10.fandom.com/wiki/Professor_Paradox

**Edit:** Answer attempt #2

> Ride

Grounded or riled up

> Rides on a bus, car and a bike keep you on the ground. A ride on an airplane keeps you up in the air

Facilitate travel, discourage you from going

> If you catch a ride, you can travel. If you miss your ride, you don't get to go. Alternatively, if you have a bumpy ride you might stop your travel.

Assumed many forms

> Amusement park rides can feature anything included statues, professors and cyborgs

**Edit:** Answer attempt #3

> Title: You're in for a turn meaning you're in for a change
>  Grounded/Rile: A well timed turn of phrase can keep you calm and grounded or get you mad and rile you up
>  Travel: A good turn of luck (you could win money) could facilitate taking a trip, a wrong turn could discourage you from going further
>  Cyborg/professor: An unexpected turn of events- The lady from Blade Runner is a cyborg (thanks @TwoBitOperation) Professor Snape is actually trying to keep Harry Potter safe | Sled (thanks @TwoBitOperation) Rosebud in Citizen Kane is his sled

Comment: Interesting start, but this is the incorrect path.

Comment: Answer attempt #2 is also incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

**Reader Beware, you're in for a**

> *Tweet!* (as in a message from Twitter)

**I can keep you grounded, or I can rile you up.**

> Tweets can stoke emotions or you can just read zen tweets

**I can facilitate your travel, or I can discourage you from going.**

> you can reach out directly to airlines etc, but you can also learn about hazards and be discouraged from being in public

**I have assumed many forms including that of a cyborg, a professor, and a statue.**

> I'm sure there's been a parody account for all three of these, multiple times...